# Change html text with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, text

I am attempting to change the value of table element id="questionLoc" to a question I have placed in an array. HTML below...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<title>Game of Thrones Trivia Quiz</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Game of Thrones Trivia Quiz</h1>
</header>
<form action="" name="mainForm">
    <p>Please choose the correct answer for the question given. Do so promptly - winter is coming.</p>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="questionLoc">
            Question Location
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Javascipt document...

```
alert("hi");

var allQuestions = [];

function question(question, choices, answer) {
                this.question = question;
                this.choices = choices;
                this.answer = answer;
}

var question1 = new question("Who is Sansa\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 2);
var question2 = new question("Who is Geoffrey\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 0);
var question3 = new question("Who is Robert\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 3);

allQuestions.push(question1, question2, question3);

$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#button').click(function {
        $('R1').html("Response 1")
    });

});

var qLoc = document.getElementById("questionLoc").innerHTML;
qLoc = allQuestions[0].question;
```

The alert("hi") is a test and only appears when I comment out my jQuery. The "questionLoc" text does not change despite the 'getDocumentByID' line. Any thoughts on why the code does not execute would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Provide jsfiddle.

Comment: In addition to other potential problems $('R1') is not likely to be a valid selector. Missing a dot or hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the console when you develop JavaScript. If you look at it, you'll see there is a syntax error in this line:

```
$('#button').click(function {
```

There are missing parentheses after the keyword `function`. That is why the `alert` does not work -- your script does not parse because of this error.

To put the first question on the page, stick to jQuery notation, and don't revert back to the native `getElementById`:

```
$("#questionLoc").text(allQuestions[0].question);
```

Note that is better to use the `text()` method over `html()` when you are putting plain text. `html()` should be used when you are inserting HTML tagged content.

Comment: Feel like a bonehead... completely disregarded the jquery tag. would have made my sample a little tidier...

Answer (score 1):

`var qLoc = document.getElementById("questionLoc").innerHTML;
qLoc = allQuestions[0].question;`

Should be changed as

`var qLoc = document.getElementById("questionLoc");
qLoc.innerHTML = allQuestions[0].question;`

In the first case u store the actual string that you want to change in 
`var qLoc`.
The thing you want to store is the element itself.

Comment: You are right, a text node can be used also. More safe.

Comment: hmmm still not changing the text. The alert still doesn't show up either...

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue is that you want to save the question element, and then set its innerHtml attribute. Same with any answer element. Of course, as I made the answers in my demo option elements, you have to set their text attribute instead.

Edited, as I realized that jQuery was a tag in this. Now using that for editing HTML elements, and for iterating over answer elements.

```js
var allQuestions = [];

function question(question, choices, answer) {
  this.question = question;
  this.choices = choices;
  this.answer = answer;
};

var question1 = new question("Who is Sansa\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 2);
var question2 = new question("Who is Geoffrey\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 0);
var question3 = new question("Who is Robert\'s mother?", ["Cercei", "Marjorie", "Catelin", "Lysa"], 3);

allQuestions.push(question1, question2, question3);

$(document).ready(function() {
  var questionEl = $(".questionEl");
  var answerEl = $(".answerEl");
  var buttonEl = $("#beginTest");
  var selectEl = $("<select>");
  var optionEl = $("<option>");
  var questionIndex = 0;
  buttonEl.on("click", function() {
    nextQuestion();
  });

  function nextQuestion() {
    questionEl.html(allQuestions[questionIndex].question);
    var thisAnswerEl = selectEl.clone();
    answerEl.html(thisAnswerEl);
    $.each(allQuestions[questionIndex].choices, function() {
      var thisOptionEl = optionEl.clone();
      thisOptionEl.attr("value", this).text(this);
      thisAnswerEl.append(thisOptionEl);
    })
    buttonEl.attr("value", "Next Question");
    questionIndex++;

  }

});
```

```css
#questionEl {
  background-color: #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>Game of Thrones Trivia Quiz</h1>
</header>
<form action="" name="mainForm">
  <p>Please choose the correct answer for the question given. Do so promptly - winter is coming.</p>
  <div class="questionEl">
  </div>
  <div class="answerEl">

  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <input id="beginTest" type="button" value="Begin!" />
  </div>
```

Comment: And yes, it'll error out when you pass the end of the question array. Beyond the scope of this exercise...